# If $(T_e(f_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges, prove: $\exists$ the limit of$(f_n)$ in Aut(G) as cont. smooth automor. of $G$ with $G$ a connected Lie grp

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Aut(G) is the group of automorphisms of G.

It is known that

-the automorphism group Aut($\mathfrak g$) is a Lie group and a closed subgroup of GL$(\mathfrak g)$

-The tangent map (at $e$) of any automorphism of $G$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak g$.

I have already proven that  the following induced map

**$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{\operatorname{Aut}} D : \Aut(G) \to \Aut(\mathfrak  g)$**

is an injective group homomorphism

Now suppose $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is  a sequence in $Aut(G)$, such that $(T_e(f_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in $Aut(\mathfrak  g)$  say to $\psi$.
Show that $ f := lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ exists as an continuous smooth automorphism of the abstract group $G$

How do I do this ? The only thing I can think about is to use the exponential map to relate the differential to the function, but I am not sure how to do this if that is  useful

I also think that the $f_n$ must be smooth right? Otherwise the $(T_e(f_n))$ would not make sense, would they?

Comment: My intuition is that the $f_n$ need not be smooth everywhere for $T_e^{\infty}$ to be smooth. Perhaps $f$ and $T_e^{\infty}$ may be smooth even when all $f_n$ are not? The limit can sometimes 'smooth out' the discontinuities. I do think $T_e^{\infty}$ should be smooth if it exists, but don't have the machinery to sketch out a proof. Good luck

Comment: Hints: It sounds like you have covered the exponential map for Lie groups. Are you aware that $f(\exp(x)) = \exp(T_e(f)(x))$ for any smooth homomorphism $f$? Replacing $f$ with $f_n$ and taking a limit shows that $f_n(\exp(x))$ coverges to $\exp(\psi(x))$. This shows that $f_n$ coverges pointwise on a neighborhood of $1$. Use connectedness and the homomorphism property to deduce that $f_n$ converges pointwise everywhere, and then argue the limit must be a smooth automorphism. Good luck.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the hints.Why is the convergence only in a neighborhood of 1 a priori? To use connectedness, am I supposed to use some other  well-known result that has connectedness as assumption? I really don't see why connectedness is useful here, I  usee it already to prove that D was injective

Comment: Your questions are very basic, which suggests that you are not yet ready to tackle this exercise. My advice is to review your notes and make sure you understand the questions/sections leading up to this one. But to answer your questions, the exponential map is only guaranteed to be bijective on suitable neighborhoods of the identity, so knowing something about $\exp(x)$ for all $x$ in the Lie algebra only tells you about a neighborhood of the identity in $G$. Meanwhile, connectedness tells you that any neighborhood of the identity generates the group.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: You should post your comments as an answer.