# $\Psi(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ is a closed subgrp of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$ in the construction of a Lie grp structure of Aut$(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

To construct a Lie group structure on $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ of a connected Lie group $G$   with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ the following steps are followed:

1. $\Psi:\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g): f \to T_ef$ is proven to be an injective group homom.
2. Show that if $(T_e(f_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak  g)$ , then
   $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is  a sequence in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$, such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ exists as an continuous smooth automorphism of the abstract group $G$
3. Observe that $\Psi(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ is a closed subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak g)$

**Assuming 1 and 2 are proven, How do I show step 3?**

Comment: It follows immediately from 2 and continuity of $\Psi$. Consider a limit point of $\Psi(\mathrm{Aut}(G))$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the answer, Could you take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4830052/if-t-ef-n-n-1-infty-converges-prove-exists-the-limit-off-n-i?noredirect=1#comment10281404_4830052 ? Its about step 2 and it is killing me.